# how do i make Intellij Idea recognize the generated resources from a custom gradle task?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle task that generates a project.properties file and places it in the resources output dir for the main sourceSet in each project that has the JavaPlugin applied (or extension of).

compileJava depends on this task however this dependency does not carry over into the Intellij-Idea IDE when I run tests (the project.properties file does not generate on rebuild), and thus causes null pointer exceptions when trying to access this file through Class.getResource().

How can i configure intellij to run this task and produce the necessary files? Is there a way of hooking it into ant so that a normal `ant soandso` build from intellij in the pre-processing section of artifact generation triggers this task?

I would prefer a way that includes direct integration with gradle.